# How to write `make_array` in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

We have `make_pair` and `make_tuple`. Is it possible to write a `make_array` function so that we can create an array like

```
auto a = make_array(1,2,3);   // equivalent to std::array<int, 3> a{ {1, 2, 3} };
```

Can anyone give an example?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lichray/6034753

Comment: Don't pay too much attention to the title of the linked question, it discusses `auto a = make_array(/* blah */)` functionality exactly